# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Artisan' not found in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am in new Laravel and trying to learn by coding. I created migration and seed and both working fine when I call them from terminal, but I wanted to try this code in my HomeController and I get a big error.

Error

```
FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 23: 
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Artisan' not found
```

Code in Home Controller

```
$hasTable = Schema::hasTable('users');      

if ($hasTable==0)
        {
            echo "call cli to migration and seed";

            $migrate = Artisan::call('migrate');
            $seed = Artisan::call('db:seed');

            echo "Migrate<br>";

            print_r($migrate);
            echo "Seed<br>";
            print_r($seed);
        }
```

I believe, if I load the correct namespace, I can avoid this error, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Assuming you have the default `Artisan` alias set in your config/app.php, you're right that you just need to import the correct namespace.

Either add this top of the file:

```
use Artisan;
```

Or use a fully qualified namespace in your code:

```
$migrate = \Artisan::call('migrate');
```

If you don't have the alias set for whatever reason, use

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
```

instead.

Comment: why `/` is here `use \Artisan;` ?

Comment: `use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;` is exessive as `Artisan` is an alias in Laravel.

Comment: @limonte You've missed the paragraph immediately above that code: _If you don't have the alias set for whatever reason_. If that alias is missing (which is perfectly reasonable, it's in user-controlled code), `use Artisan` or `\Artisan::...` will get you a nice fatal error

Comment: Thanks @Clive . It certainly helped :)

Comment: It seems like Lumen doesn't have `Artisan` aliased, so this was helpful to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you just reference a class like `Artisan::call('db:seed')` PHP searches for the class in your **current namespace**.

In this case that's `App\Http\Controllers`. However the `Artisan` class obviously doesn't exists in your namespace for controllers but rather in the Laravel framework namespace. It has also an alias that's in the *global* namespace.

You can either reference the alias in the root namespace by prepending a backslash:

```
return \Artisan::call('db:seed');
```

Or add an import statement at the top:

```
use Artisan;
```